# Checkbox to select all or deselect all in a listview not bound to dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a report page which displays a view for a set of data that we report off of. This view has about 40 fields. The user can query and filter the data to get what they need and then export it to an excel report which is then automatically emailed to management that needs to see the information.

Because not all of the fields are needed for every report I also have a list box next to the view with checkboxes to hide or show any fields. I have been trying to figure out how to get all checkboxes checked or unchecked by selecting checkbox in header. The xaml for the list box is bound to the IsVisible property of the fields in the grid and looks like so.

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, ElementName=reportGrid}"  SelectionMode="Multiple">  
   <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Width="50">
               <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                           <CheckBox x:Name="checkall" IsChecked="{Binding IsMainSelected}" Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource Spy}, Path=DataContext}" />
                     </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>                                                     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                                            
                    <DataTemplate >
                       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Field" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
           </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

The reference to the Spy static resource came from this article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27432/Artificial-Inheritance-Contexts-in-WPF

However, the problem I am encountering with every solution is the fact that the checkboxes in the listview are bound to a dataset. In this case the checkboxes are bound to the visibility of a column in a grid (on object on a page). Everything I have tried has failed. It's probably a simple solution but darned if I can figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I came up with a solution to this problem using code behind. If there is  a way to do this without using code behind I am all ears, but this was fairly simple and straight forward number one and number two it doesn't really break the rules of keeping logic out of code behind.

The xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, ElementName=reportGrid}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                              Margin="5,160,25,30" SelectionMode="Multiple">                           
                        <ListView.View>  
                            <GridView x:Name="gl">
                                <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                                        <DataTemplate x:Name="fieldChecked"  >
                                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Margin="0" x:Name="chkSelectAll" Click="chkSelectAll_Click" IsChecked="True" />
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Check/Uncheck All" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Header}" Width="110"></GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

The code behind

```
 private void chkSelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkSelectAll.IsChecked.Value == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items.Count; i++)
            {                    
                ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lv.Items[i]);

                if (lvi != null)
                {
                    CheckBox c = lvi.FindChildByType<CheckBox>();
                    c.IsChecked = true;                        
                }
            }   
        }
        else
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < lv.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lv.Items[i]);
                if (lvi != null)
                {
                    CheckBox c = lvi.FindChildByType<CheckBox>();
                    c.IsChecked = false;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

One caveat was that the list view I had to scroll down to bottom to see all of the fields. If I didn't do this it wouldn't uncheck all of the fields. I also had to put in the line of code 
if(lvi != null) as well because if you didn't scroll down it would think an item in the list was null and crash.

Anyway it isn't perfect but that is how I fixed it. Any better solutions using MVVM that isn't so blanking complicated to implement please enlighten me.

Thanks

Comment: Update...I could not figure out how to come up with a solution using MVVM paradigm, but did figure something out using the code behind. I have found that sometimes the code behind is the easiest way to do it. As long as we don't have any true logic in the code behind then who cares really? Anyway. the xml

Answer (score 0):

Whoa.. This is an old question and it remained unanswered for whatever reason.

Resorting to `VisualTreeHelper` type of stuff is almost never an optimal approach in WPF. It is not even "easier" than a proper [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-based approach.

in this case, since you're dealing with **UI-specific** concerns (showing or hiding a DataGrid's columns), there is no ViewModel, so MVVM does not apply here, and code behind is perfectly valid.

However, you're looking at the wrong end of the problem: trying to manipulate the CheckBoxes (the Binding **Target**) as opposed to simply manipulating the Binding **Source** (the columns themselves):

```
private void chkSelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var visible = chkSelectAll.IsChecked ?? false;
    foreach (var column in reportGrid.Columns)
        column.Visibility = visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;      
}
```

by modifying the value of the `Visibility` property, the read-only `IsVisible` property of each column will be updated and the binding will carry the new value to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property of each corresponding CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this anwser like I did, there is a nice way to solve the scrolling issue Paul mentioned: just scroll in the code-behind!

```
listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1]);
listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.Items[0]);
```

After that you can do the ItemContainerGenerator stuff without getting null.

And if you want to optimize responsiveness (especially for larger lists that do not change often): you only have to query the ItemContainerGenerator when the source content of your listView has changed. So if you put the CheckBoxes in a separate list, you only have to query the ItemContainerGenerator the first time the user clicks the (De)Select All checkbox...

But you should do this in the Event handler of the (De)Select All checkbox, because if you query the ItemContainerGenerator for the CheckBoxes right after you set the itemsSource and do the scrolling, you still end up with nulls (I assume because the GUI hasn't had the time to render the ListView properly yet at that time).